# Extracting stacktrace from large crashes

Tags: gdb, kernel, crash-reports, coredump

I have a crash handler installed at:

```
/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

Which pipes the incoming coredump to a file and then extracts the stacktrace via gdb.

The problem is that sometimes these coredumps can be very very large (often over 30GB). In these cases, users wait and wait while the coredump is written to disk before the application hangs.

Any suggestions on how to handle these very large coredumps in a non-blocking fashion? I don't care about the coredump per se, the stacktrace is what is valuable.

I don't have access to source, so answers such as https://serverfault.com/questions/627747/non-blocking-core-dump-on-linux aren't that practical.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I don't have access to source, so answers such as https://serverfault.com/questions/627747/non-blocking-core-dump-on-linux aren't that practical.

If the application is dynamically linked, you can `LD_PRELOAD` google coredumper into it, so the answer is somewhat practical.

Another possible alternative is http://github.com/tbricks/tbstack.

Certainly dumping 30GB of RAM just to throw most of it away is wasteful.

Comment: Thanks! tbstack worked like a charm! Any suggestions on how to demangle the function names in the stack? Btw, I'm wary of LD_PRELOAD since the production environment I work in supports a very large number of third party tools, each of which would need to be tested with this variable set. Thanks again!

Comment: Hmmmm... actually this might not quite work for my case. Running the utility on a healthy process works as expected. But, running it on a recently crashed process as part of the core_pattern hook results in 0k being copied from the process. Is that expected?